# Marker is not working(not exact location is displaying), only world Map is visible in Frgament

Tags: android, android-studio

**CustomMapFragment**

```
public class CustomMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

public static final LatLng NurissLife = new LatLng(28.602012, 77.098750);
private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
    // FragmentManager fm=getChildFragmentManager();
    supportMapFragment=SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    //supportMapFragment=(SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager
     //().findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position
         (NurissLife).title("Nuriss LifeCare"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom
         (NurissLife, 15));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, 
           null);
        }
    });
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

}
 }
```

**Fragment xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map_content"
tools:context="com.demo.stuartabhi.nurisslife.Fragment.ContactFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map_container">

</FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>'
```

Marker is not working(exact location is not displaying), only world Map 
is visible in Fragement

`OnMapReady` is not working either showing 
no error in log, location code being described in OnMapReady method.

Please help regarding this, how to access the described location LatLng NurissLife inside `SupportMapFragment`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the `MapFragment` you're adding the marker to is a different instance than the one visible to you in your app. You need to use the reference of the `MapFragment` you've added in the XML layout.

Comment: public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {
    private CustomMapFragment mapFragment;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact,container,false);
      mapFragment=new CustomMapFragment();
     transaction=getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     transaction.add(R.id.map_container,mapFragment).commit();
        return rootView;}

Comment: still not found any solution , I have used nested fragment ContactFragment extends Fragment then CustomMapFragment extends SupportMApFragment

Comment: Your implementation of `CustomMapFragment` isn't really working like it should. Answering this question. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

If you extend SupportMapFragment, there is no need to inflate any xml layout.  Just call `this.getMapAsync()` in order to get a reference to the GoogleMap:

```
public class CustomMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements
        OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public CustomMapFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d("MyMap", "onMapReady");
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(NurissLife).title("Nuriss LifeCare"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(NurissLife, 15));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you @Daniel  great help, I have been stuck for more than 2 hours to resolve it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a method `getCustomMapFragment()` in your `Activity` class like this:

```
private SupportMapFragment getCustomMapFragment(){
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    supportMapFragment= SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position
                    (NurissLife).title("Nuriss LifeCare"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom
                    (NurissLife, 15));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000,
                    null);
        }
    });
    return supportMapFragment;
}
```

And when you perform your `FragmentTransaction`, try this:

```
...
transaction=getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.map_container,getCustomMapFragment()).commit();
...
```

Also, with this implementation, the `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` line in your XML might be unnecessary.

Comment: Did you remove the line `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` ?

Also, try `transaction.replace()` instead of `transaction.add()`.